# Passing data from view to controller and from controller back to view

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have a problem writing a simple app in ASP.NET.
My idea is to pass data from that form to create a movie in my controller and then I want this controller (AddMovie) to send this movie to my movieList and I want this to be shown in the view.
I tried some ways, but none worked. How can I do that?

View:

```
@model IEnumerable<Movie>
@{
    // ViewData["Title"] = "MovieView";

    ViewBag.Title = "Welcome to My Page";

}
<h1>MoviesView</h1>

@foreach (var item in Model)
{
<div class="text-center">
    <p>Id:item.Id </p>
    <p>Name:item.Name</p>
    <p>Author: item.Author</p>
   
</div>
<br />
}
<br />
<form asp-controller="MoviesController" method="post">
    Id: <input type="text" name="movieId" /><br />
    Name: <input type="text" name="movieName" /><br />
    Author: <input type="text" name="movieAuthor" />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" formaction="AddMovie" /> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;

</form>
<p>@ViewBag.Result</p>
```

Controller:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using WebMVCAPP_L.Models;

namespace WebMVCAPP_L.Controllers
{
    public class MoviesController : Controller
    {
        List<Movie> movieList = new List<Movie>();

        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            return View(movieList);
        }
        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult AddMovie()
        {
            int id = Convert.ToInt32(HttpContext.Request.Form["movieId"].ToString());
            string name = HttpContext.Request.Form["movieName"].ToString();
            string author = HttpContext.Request.Form["movieAuthor"].ToString();

            Movie movie = new Movie(id,name,author);
            movieList.Add(movie);
            return View("Index");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I recommend you, instead of providing so big chunks of code, to provide only the lines that are not working.

Answer (score 0):

When you routing from one action to another action then you need to use tempdata.

```
namespace WebMVCAPP_L.Controllers
{
    public class MoviesController : Controller
    {
        List<Movie> movieList = new List<Movie>();

        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            if(TempData["myData"]!=null){

                movieList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Movie>>((String)TempData["myData"]);
             }
            return View(movieList);
        }
        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult AddMovie()
        {
            int id = Convert.ToInt32(HttpContext.Request.Form["movieId"].ToString());
            string name = HttpContext.Request.Form["movieName"].ToString();
            string author = HttpContext.Request.Form["movieAuthor"].ToString();

            Movie movie = new Movie(id,name,author);
            movieList.Add(movie);
             String str = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(movieList)
             TempData["myData"] = str ;
            return View("Index");
        }
    }
}

<form asp-action="AddMovie" asp-controller="Movies">

    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: I have updated my answer. you need to pass value like above in your form.

Comment: I think a list of movies will need to be preserved longer than a single HTTP request.

Comment: I have change code, Asp.Net Core MVC not supported complex data type for TempData currently. It only support string for now. It through this exception while serialize data, if we pass other then string.

I serialize my list to json and then save in TempData.

Here is how I did this. I create extension method to add and retrieve data from TempData.

Answer (score 0):

Before anything else, you need some way of persisting your `List<Movie>()`. HTTP, and therefore MVC, is stateless. Ideally you would be using a database, but you could use `Session` for testing purposes:

```
List<Movie> movieList
{
    get
    {
        if (Session["movieList"] == null)
        {
            Session["movieList"] = new List<Movie>();
        }
        return Session["movieList"] as List<Movie>;
    }
}
```

Yo also need to add `asp-action` to your form to post back to your `AddMovie` method:

```
<form asp-controller="MoviesController" asp-action="AddMovie" method="post">
```

Then, change your method signature:

```
public IActionResult AddMovie(int id, string name, string author)
```

The MVC framework will automatically bind form fields to arguments of the same name.

Finally, return a HTTP redirect rather than the view itself:

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult AddMovie()
{
    Movie movie = new Movie(id, name, author);
    movieList.Add(movie);
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

The browser will then perform a HTTP GET to your `Index` method for the (persisted) movie list.

Answer (score 0):

It shows me something like this `` An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
InvalidOperationException: The 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.Infrastructure.DefaultTempDataSerializer' cannot serialize an object of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[WebMVCAPP_L.Models.Movie]'.
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.Infrastructure.DefaultTempDataSerializer.Serialize(IDictionary<string, object> values) ``

````
Stack Query Cookies Headers Routing 

InvalidOperationException: The 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.Infrastructure.DefaultTempDataSerializer' cannot serialize an object of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[WebMVCAPP_L.Models.Movie]'.
    Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.Infrastructure.DefaultTempDataSerializer.Serialize(IDictionary<string, object> values)
    Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.CookieTempDataProvider.SaveTempData(HttpContext context, IDictionary<string, object> values)
    Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.TempDataDictionary.Save()
    Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.Filters.SaveTempDataFilter.SaveTempData(IActionResult result, ITempDataDictionaryFactory factory, IList<IFilterMetadata> filters, HttpContext httpContext)
    Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.Filters.SaveTempDataFilter.OnResultExecuted(ResultExecutedContext context)
    Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.ResultNext<TFilter, TFilterAsync>(ref State next, ref Scope scope, ref object state, ref bool isCompleted)
    Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.InvokeResultFilters()
    Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeNextResourceFilter>g__Awaited|24_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, object state, bool isCompleted)
    Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResourceExecutedContextSealed context)
    Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Next(ref State next, ref Scope scope, ref object state, ref bool isCompleted)
    Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.InvokeFilterPipelineAsync()
    Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)
    Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.<Invoke>g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)
    Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
    Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)```
````